# How to use NSEventMask with Swift

Tags: swift, macos

Why am I getting a compiler error indicating the boolean OR function "|" cannot be used with in the following manner:

```
localEvent = self.window.nextEventMatchingMask(NSEventMask.LeftMouseUpMask | NSEventMask.LeftMouseDraggedMask)
```

EDIT:

Here is what I eventually found to work

```
localEvent = self.window!.nextEventMatchingMask(Int(NSEventMask.LeftMouseUpMask.rawValue | NSEventMask.LeftMouseDraggedMask.rawValue))!
```

Comment: Perhaps `[.LeftMouseUpMask, .LeftMouseDraggedMask]`?

Comment: The I get a "Contextual type Int cannot be used with an Array Literal" error

Comment: I can not find the documentation for that method. The closest is `
- nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:` , and the first param is defined as an `Int`...? Can't find any sample code in Swift either on the internet. Guess OSX isn't as popular...

Comment: Perhaps this can help: http://nshipster.com/rawoptionsettype/

Comment: @DuncanGroenewald try                     Int(NSEventMask.LeftMouseUpMask.union(NSEventMask.LeftMouseDraggedMask).rawValue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
localEvent = window.nextEventMatchingMask(Int(NSEventMask.LeftMouseUpMask.rawValue))
```

or

```
localEvent = window.nextEventMatchingMask(
                Int(NSEventMask.LeftMouseUpMask.union(.LeftMouseDraggedMask).rawValue))
```